# Need help parsing a text file and splitting it into key values in C#

Tags: c#, string, parsing, text, stream

I'm trying to parse a text file with a specific format and split it into key values that I can later edit externally so I can build them back into another text file. The way I'm trying to do it seems pretty dirty to me, I'm using a stream to traverse the file until I reach quotes and braces by using while loops. It mostly works until I reach a specific point where I either stumble upon a closing brace or jump over some terminating quote that completely screws up the formatting. I've tried a bunch of different changes but it just doesn't work right.

The files I'm trying to parse have this type of format:

testparse.txt

```
"testparse.txt"
{
    "TestElement"
    {
        "value1"                    "0"
        "value2"                    "stuff"
        "value3"                    "morestuff"
        "value4"                    "25"
        "value5"                    "text"
        "value6"                    "21"
    }

    "TestElement2"
    {
        "value1"                    "0"
        "value2"                    "1"
        "value3"                    "2"
        "value4"                    "3"
        "value5"                    "4"
        "value6"                    "5"
    }

}
```

I'm interested in packing the names and the values ("value1", "0") into KeyValues which I later pack into Elements which I later pack into Files. I'm using strings for everything.

Here's my code:
Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace hudParse
{    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char qt = '\"';
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("D:/Desktop/testparse.txt");
            HudFile file = new HudFile();
            string s = "";
            Seek(sr,qt);

            do
            {
                s += (char)sr.Read();
            }
            while(sr.Peek() != qt);

            sr.Read();
            file.Name = s;            
            Console.WriteLine("Filename is " + s);
            Seek(sr,'{');

            //Main loop
            do
            {
                HudElement element = new HudElement();                
                Seek(sr,qt);
                s = "";

                do
                {
                    s += (char)sr.Read();
                }
                while(sr.Peek() != qt);
                sr.Read();

                element.Name = s;
                Console.WriteLine("New Element name is " + s);

                Seek(sr,'{');
                do
                {
                    s = "";
                    KeyValue kv = new KeyValue();
                    Seek(sr,qt);
                    do
                    {
                        s += (char)sr.Read();
                    }
                    while(sr.Peek() != qt);
                    kv.Name = s;
                    sr.Read();

                    s = "";

                    Seek(sr,qt);
                    do
                    {
                        s += (char)sr.Read();
                    }
                    while(sr.Peek() != qt);
                    kv.Value = s;
                    sr.Read();

                    element.Add(kv);
                    Console.WriteLine("KeyValue added to " + element.Name + ": " + kv.ToString());
                }
                while(sr.Read() != '}');


            }
            while((sr.Read() != '}') || (sr.Read() != -1));

            file.Write();
            sr.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Created file " + file.Name);
        }
        static void Seek(StreamReader sr, char c)
        {            
            while(sr.Read() != c);
        }
    }
}
```

KeyValue.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace hudParse
{
    class KeyValue
    {
        string m_Name;
        string m_Value;                

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return m_Name;
            }

            set
            {                
                m_Name = value.Trim();
            }
        }

        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                return m_Value;
            }

            set
            {                
                m_Value = value.Trim();
            }
        }

        public KeyValue()
        {
            m_Name = null;
            m_Value = null;            
        }
        public KeyValue(string name, string value)
        {
            m_Name = name;
            m_Value = value;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return '\"'+ m_Name + '\"' + '\t' + '\t' + '\"'+ m_Value + '\"';
        }

        public string GetName()
        {
            return m_Name;
        }

        public string GetValue()
        {
            return m_Value;
        }

        public bool isNull()
        {
            if(m_Name == null)
                return true;
            return false;
        }          

    }
}
```

I'm sure there is a better way of doing all this that I'm missing so I don't get spaces, tabs and newlines breaking my parsing. Here's the other classes associated with my code.

[HudElement.cs](http://pastebin.com/ecnQVqKT)
[HudFile.cs](http://pastebin.com/sn8FvauQ)

Comment: The text file looks like JSON. You could look at serializing it into a class and then access the values from there.

Comment: Are these JSON files you're working with? If so, I recommend that you czech out JSON.NET. At any rate, be aware that there is a Dictionary class you can use which has key/value members; there is also a KVP class available to you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: These are resource files used for multiple things inside the source engine. I'll have a look at the dictionary class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data looks like a broken JSON, so I think the easiest way to parse it would be transforming it to a valid JSON and then using some default tools like JSON.NET. Your data should look like

```
{
 "t1": {
   "key1":"value1", 
   "key2":"value2"
  },
 "t2": {
   "key3":"value3", 
   "key4":"value4"
 }
}
```

The above sample is for `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>` type.